# Footer is Not Fit to Datatables Jquery After First Load

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I have a problem with datatables jquery. My dashboard footer is not fit to datatables when the page first load a lot of data (paggging).

Here's the screenshot:
[Click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61SPb.png)

After i try to open inspect element, or try to zoom out/in the page, the footer will automatically fit.

The footer should be like this:
[Click for screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNAdr.png)

Video record: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vSjzqGuknJhl_jPtnZTdf5mNYTNlvBmf/view?usp=drivesdk

Thanks before.

My datatables code:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>No</th>
<th>Nama Trainset</th>
<th>Status Aktif</th>
<th>Aksi</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($trainset_data as $trainset)
{
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" width="80px"><?php echo ++$start ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $trainset->nm_trainset ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $trainset->aktif ?></td>
<td style="text-align:center" width="200px">
<?php 
echo anchor(site_url('trainset/update/'.$trainset->id_trainset),'Perbarui'); 
echo ' | '; 
echo anchor(site_url('trainset/delete/'.$trainset->id_trainset),'Hapus','onclick="javasciprt: return confirm(\'Apakah Anda yakin akan menghapus data ini?\')"'); 
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you have live version instead of screenshot?

Comment: wait, i will try to record

Comment: Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vSjzqGuknJhl_jPtnZTdf5mNYTNlvBmf/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your HTML markup. can we [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186626/ask-chad) ?

Comment: what about if you change `<?php foreach ($trainset_data as $trainset) { ?>` to `<?php foreach ($trainset_data as $trainset) : ?>` and `<?php } ?>` to `<?php endforeach; ?>` ?

Comment: @ichadhr i already change foreach like you said, but its not working. Im sorry i cant chat, because i dont have enough poin